# Unwanted redirects in chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

When I type a search in chrome on OS X it automatically does another search after I hit enter. This seems like malware. I found a few extensions in chrome that I did not install -- and I removed them. Many of the extensions listed in this article were in my chrome http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-amazon-shopping-assistant-by-spigot/

I uninstalled chrome by dragging the application to the trash -- then reinstalled.

I ran a scan with sophos that did not find any malware.

What else can I do to fix this problem? Is there a chrome setting that might be causing this problem? Chrome searches for hbo go after I hit enter.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Does the behavior occur there as well? If so, are you getting your internet service over a cable modem? Your ISP may be hijacking your search requests.